# how to get exact img src in xpath

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

if you inspect the page to get img src, you'll see sth like this:`/images/March/img1.jpeg`. but as you know that's not a real address. I want to scrape this page and get the proper src value. how can I do that?
thx in advance.

```
<?php
$content=file_get_content('example.com');
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath=new DOMXpath();
$img=$xpath->query("(//img)[2]/@src");
foreach($img as $val){
   $images=$val->nodeValue;//just returns img/march/img1.jpeg
                           //instead of www.example.com/img.....
}
?>
```

Comment: Well you know the domain you are requesting so append that to the `src`s value if it isn't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make Absolute path manually like this:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('example.com');

$dom     = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXpath();
$img   = $xpath->query("(//img)[2]/@src");

// Make Absolute Url
function getAbsUrl($value, $baseurl)
{
    $Parsed = parse_url($value);

    if (empty($Parsed['host'])) {
        // Relative
        return rtrim($baseurl, '/') . '/' . ltrim($Parsed['path'], '/');
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}

foreach ($img as $val) {
    $images = getAbsUrl($val->nodeValue, 'http://www.example.com/');
}
```

Comment: when I put the `$images` to address bar in browser, I get 404 error not found. could you take a look at this [link](http://www.espc2016.com)

Comment: @davidcamry As i see, all the page loaded in a iframe which hosted in: http://esaconferencebureau.com/2016-events/16A12, so you have to set host to this: esaconferencebureau.com which makes image url like this: http://esaconferencebureau.com/images/default-source/16a12_images/604479_a2-poster-espc_lr_03---lowr.jpg?sfvrsn=0